# Extract numbers from tab-delimited files

Tags: regex, linux, awk, grep

I have a tab-delimited .txt file that has 4 rows and 4 columns. I want to extract numbers (integer, decimal number and scientific notation) from the txt file. The numbers are in row 2-4 and column 2-4 (the first row is the header, and the first column is the rowname).
The content of the file is pasted below:

```
component   sigma          h2           h2_se
G           -5.55758e-19   -0.0964725   26.3887
GxE         6.13144e-18    1.09647      26.3651
noise       0              0            0
```

This is the desired output, and due to further processing for this output, I would like to have newline `\n` appended at the end.

`-5.55758e-19 -0.0964725 26.3887 6.13144e-18 1.09647 26.3651 0 0 0`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Below is some code I tried, which does not yield what I want:

`grep -o '0.[[:digit:]]*' myfile`

`grep -o '[[:digit:]]*' myfile`

====================================================

Here's the code that worked for me, and a lot of thanks to @tink!

`awk 'NR>1 {printf "%s %s %s ", $2,$3,$4}END{printf "\n"}' myfile`

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this? Please include any relevant code in the post.

Comment: @kiner_shah Hi, I know very little about grep or awk, I can post some code but I'm unsure if they will be helpful at all.

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried.

Comment: @tink I tried pasting the original text, but it looks like the tab and newline are shown as space in the editor...

Comment: Most likely still better than having to type all that :)

Comment: @tink Thanks for the help! I tried it and it prints an empty line. The text is pasted

Comment: @tink Hey it works now - I ran it with the wrong file name (thus the wrong format) and I changed to it `awk 'NR>1 {printf "%s %s %s ", $2,$3,$4}END{printf "\n"}'`, because only the first row is unwanted. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: That will add a trailing blank to the output. Also `print ""` is better than `printf "\n"` since the former simply uses `ORS` while the latter uses the hard-coded string that it hopes `ORS` is set to.

Comment: Please post answers as answers where they can be up/downvoted by the community and appear as answered for people searching the forum, don't just include the answer in your question and leave it apparently unanswered.

Comment: @EdMorton Hi, the newline is added for some other processing in the next step, and an explanation for the newline is added to the post. Also, I posted my own answer now.

Comment: Either approach adds a newline, my point is that adding the newline by `print ""` is better than adding it by `printf "\n"` for the reason I stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR>1{$1=""; out=out $0} END{$0=out; $1=$1; print}' file
-5.55758e-19 -0.0964725 26.3887 6.13144e-18 1.09647 26.3651 0 0 0
```

Alternatively either of these would also work:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{printf "%s%s %s %s", sep, $2, $3, $4; sep=OFS} END{print ""}' file
-5.55758e-19 -0.0964725 26.3887 6.13144e-18 1.09647 26.3651 0 0 0
```

```
$ awk 'NR>1{printf "%s%s %s %s", (NR>2 ? OFS : ""), $2, $3, $4} END{print ""}' file
-5.55758e-19 -0.0964725 26.3887 6.13144e-18 1.09647 26.3651 0 0 0
```

If your first field can contain a blank then add `-F'\t'` at the start of the script.

Comment: Some explanation here: `NR>1{ ... }` : only execute this if we are not processing the fist line/record. `$1=""` empty the first field and rebuild the record `$0` as `$1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4` with `OFS` a single space. `out = out $0` postfix the variable `out` with the record. `END{...}` do this when the end of the file is reached. `$0=out` assign `out` to the current record and do field splitting. Note that the current record starts with a space. `$1=$1` rebuild the record `$0` as `$1 OFS $2 OFS $3`, a fascinating way to get rid of the first space. `print` print the current record `$0`

Comment: Note: this will fail if there is a space in the first column of the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cut -f2- < file | tail -n+2 | paste -s - | tr '\t' ' '
-5.55758e-19 -0.0964725 26.3887 6.13144e-18 1.09647 26.3651 0 0 0
```

Comment: nice use of cut and paste, especially as they work on tab-delimted files by default.

Answer (score 1):

The following `grep` extracts all words that are integers or reals:

```
$ grep -owE '[-+]?[0-9]*([.][0-9]*([Ee][-+][0-9]+)?)?' file | tr '\n' ' '
```

This just works due to the nature of your input file.

A robust way, would be the awk program presented by Ed Morton [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69899491/8344060)

Answer (score 1):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
component   sigma          h2           h2_se
G           -5.55758e-19   -0.0964725   26.3887
GxE         6.13144e-18    1.09647      26.3651
noise       0              0            0
```

with field separaterd by single `\t` then

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=""}NR>1{$1="";print}' file.txt
```

output

```
 -5.55758e-19 -0.0964725 26.3887 6.13144e-18 1.09647 26.3651 0 0 0
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` to use empty string as Output Row Separator (`ORS`) then for every line after first, I set first field to empty string and `print` such altered line. Note that output string has leading space and has not newline at end, if you need to have newline add `END{print "\n"}`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Alternatively you might pipe some `linux` utilities to get similar effect as follows

```
tail -3 file.txt | cut -f 2,3,4 | tr '\n\t' '  '
```

output

```
-5.55758e-19 -0.0964725 26.3887 6.13144e-18 1.09647 26.3651 0 0 0
```

Explanation: get 3 last lines using `tail` then get columns `2,3,4` via `cut` then change newlines to spaces and tab to spaces using `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that worked for me, and a lot of thanks to @tink! The `\n` is added for the next step processing.

`awk 'NR>1 {printf "%s %s %s ", $2,$3,$4}END{printf "\n"}' myfile`

For an output that does not have a trailing space, use

`awk 'NR>1 {printf "%s %s %s ", $2,$3,$4}' myfile`

Comment: Both of those scripts output a trailing space, the 2nd one just doesn't also output a terminating newline and so is not a valid POSIX text file.

Comment: @EdMorton I see! Thanks for pointing that out. Can you check whether I got it right in the edited post?

Comment: No, you see that space at the end of `"%s %s %s "`? THAT is the trailing space you're printing. You'd need a different approach to avoid it, e.g. see my answer which I just updated to show how to do a hard-coded print of fields as you're doing in your answer but with the terminating newline and without a trailing space.